# How to store a specific node id on firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm storing data on Firebase but I would like to give a specific name to my node id (not a random one generate by firebase). Here is how I push my data :

```
  firebase.database().ref('events').push(event)
    .then((data) => {
      const key = data.key
      commit('createEvent', {
        ...event,
        id: key
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

In my data i'm pushing a parameter call 'title', and I would like to use it also in my node id. Do you thing I can manage this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the location in the database you want to write to, don't use push(), which always generates a unique id.  Build a reference to the location you want to write, and just use set() to write the data at that location.

```
firebase.database().ref("/the/location/you/want/to/write").set(your_data)
```

Comment: aaaah i just deleted all my database by trying this !! Thanks anyway :)